# XSLT: Handling embedded HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT to turn XML files into other XML files suitable to be read by another program. The problem I'm having is a node in the XML files I'm trying to transform has a ton of embedded br tags instead of actual whitespace, and I can't seem to figure out how to deal with these. Both value-of and copy-of XSLT elements strip out the BR tags but don't actually process them correctly so the resulting XML is very ugly. Ideally I would just like the HTML to be processed for me, but preserving the HTML into a string that I could process myself inside the XSLT would be fine as well.

Example Text:

```
 <Node>
        <Node2>
          <Node3>
            <Node4>
              <p>Text:<br/><br/>Text2 <br/><br/>Text3<br/><br/>
```

XSLT:

```
<Test><xsl:value-of select="Node/Node2/Node3/Node4"/></Test>
```

Output:

```
<Test>Text: Text2 Text3</Test>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Test>Text:

Text2

Text3</Test>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `br` tags with the XML entity for a line feed or carriage return depending on the output requirements.

```
<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> <!-- line feed -->
    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text> <!-- Carriage return -->
</xsl:template>
```

edit: Instead of using `value-of` which just takes the literal value of any and all text under the element, try something along this line:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Test><xsl:apply-templates select="Node/Node2/Node3/Node4/*" /></Test>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> <!-- line feed -->
    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text> <!-- Carriage return -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()|text()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|text()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: How exactly does this work? I've defined the template, but I'm unsure how exactly to call it to produce the output that is required.

Comment: Lego, thank you very much for taking the time. This helps a lot. However, a few questions... what exactly is the "@*|node()" construction doing? When I apply this in my XSLT it does exactly what I want regarding the br tags, however it also seems to not preserve the original text, making me just get 147 blank lines.

Comment: Eeek... I forgot to add `text()`. Read up on the [idenity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which is basically the "copy everything" transform used as a base which trying to modify minimal parts of an XML document. If the answer is now helpful, you can click the green tick to accept it so other users know your question has an acceptable answer.

Comment: Actually.. the text() wasn't needed. I found my original line was `xsl:apply-templates select="Node1/Node2/Node3/Node4/p/*"` and removing the /p/ produced the output I wanted. Thank you so much Lego.